# How to delete files from blob container that are older than 30 days?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, policy, retention

I am looking for a way to delete stored files in a blob container called `reports` that are older than 30 days or set any other retention policy that would make sense

As far as I see Microsoft only writes about retention policies for Logs and Metadata.
Is this possible? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Storage Lifecycle policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal) to achieve that.

```
#Initialize the following with your resource group and storage account names
$rgname = ""
$accountName = ""

#Create a new action object
$action = Add-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyAction -BaseBlobAction Delete -daysAfterModificationGreaterThan 2555
$action = Add-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyAction -InputObject $action -BaseBlobAction TierToArchive -daysAfterModificationGreaterThan 90
$action = Add-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyAction -InputObject $action -BaseBlobAction TierToCool -daysAfterModificationGreaterThan 30
$action = Add-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyAction -InputObject $action -SnapshotAction Delete -daysAfterCreationGreaterThan 90

# Create a new filter object
# PowerShell automatically sets BlobType as “blockblob” because it is the only available option currently
$filter = New-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyFilter -PrefixMatch ab,cd

#Create a new rule object
#PowerShell automatically sets Type as “Lifecycle” because it is the only available option currently
$rule1 = New-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicyRule -Name Test -Action $action -Filter $filter

#Set the policy
$policy = Set-AzStorageAccountManagementPolicy -ResourceGroupName $rgname -StorageAccountName $accountName -Rule $rule1
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal#add-or-remove-a-policy

Comment: In 3 minutes you came up with this much code :). Awesome!

Comment: I've applied that but haven't saw effects yet. How often are these rules executed?

Comment: `I created a new policy, why do the actions not run immediately?
The platform runs the lifecycle policy once a day. Once you configure a policy, it can take up to 24 hours for some actions to run for the first time.`